# issue with Date while scooping data from oracle

Tags: apache, hadoop2

I am trying to scoop import Date column from oracle database to Avro format. 
Below is the sample on how I am executing. My options file content

```
--target-dir
/.. /
--delete-target-dir
--as-avrodatafile
--query
Select chg_ts from abc
--map-column-java chg_ts=String
```

My scoop import contains

```
sqoop import -D oraoop.timestamp.string=false --options-file $1 --options-file $2 --fetch-size=0 -m 1 --mapreduce-job-name $job_name"_"$instance
```

After doing the above steps I am still getting the date as  "type" : [ "null", "long" ] in avro file and takes Bigint in Hive.

Please guide me if I am missing something here.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"takes BigInt in Hive"*? Did you try to map that column as a `DATE` in your `CREATE TABLE`? Although 'm not 100% sure how the AVRO SerDe maps a Hive *DATE* datatype, based on the Parquet Serde (which uses AVRO internally) it should be simply a Unix timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01) stored as a *LONG*.

Comment: Or, explicitly convert your Oracle date to an ISO-formatted string, that Hive can easily convert back to a *DATE* >> `select to_char(wtf, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from blahblah` and map as `STRING` in your `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply. 
At this point the option suggested by you looks good, but is it possible to get the chg_ts=timestamp? 
i have also tried  --map-column-java chg_ts=timestamp but it takes as bigint in hive.

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean exactly by *"takes as bigint in hive"*.